# How to avoid Mechanize to parse an url of a file or image?

Tags: mechanize

I'm using the gem mechanize in my rails app to scrap an web page data.
I use it this way:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
document = agent.get("http://www.google.com")
```

This works just fine and the response is quick. However, when the url is something that returns a file or an image, it downloads the file and it can take a while. But I'm not even interested in the content of the file, I just want to avoid fetching them.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
document = agent.get("https://speakerd.s3.amazonaws.com/presentations/42e9703056c60131ff9556cea4acc4c2/Buildlightsaber_preso.pdf")
```

Mechanize has some sort of configure this? Or I should create some regexp before to validate URl's (but this sounds not scalable)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by making a fast lookup with [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

```
url = "https://speakerd.s3.amazonaws.com/presentations/42e9703056c60131ff9556cea4acc4c2/Buildlightsaber_preso.pdf" 
(RestClient.head(url).headers[:content_type] =~ /text\/html/).nil?
```